# vim: define command for grep + copen + incremental search

Tags: vim, grep, incremental-search

I'd like to define a custom command for doing the following steps: grep the current word, copen, incremental search the grep'ed word. Here's the command I'm using:

```
nmap <C-p> :execute "grep! -Irn " . shellescape(expand("<cword>")) . " ."<cr>:copen<cr>:g/<cword>/<cr>
```

But the second cword is expanded to the current word after the quickfix window is opened. How can I use the word that's used by grep earlier?

Comment: store word to a variable, use it later. `:let word = expand("<cword>") | ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you got `<cword>` into `grep`:

```
nmap <C-p> :execute "grep! -Irn " . shellescape(expand("<cword>")) . " .\<cr>:copen\<cr>:g/" . expand("<cword>"). "/\<cr>"<cr>
```

Some thoughts:

- Set the search register instead of `:g`. E.g. `:let @/ = "foo"`
- Use `nnoremap`
- Use `escape()` to make it more resilient. See `:h escape(`
- Maybe use `:vimgrep`. See `:h :vimg`
- This is a similar problems solved by the following plugins: [visual star](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search), [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim), and [Ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)